# Is there an if/then condition in shopping cart promotions?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions

I am running 1.7.0.0, though that shouldn't matter too much. I am trying to create a promotion that discounts certain products if another product is purchased. In this case, if customer buys a certain music player and adds certain CDs to the order, the price of each CD would be discounted 10%. I've learned a lot this evening about what I can do with promotions, but I can't find anything like this.

Thank you,

John

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting the relevant attributes to have Frontend Properties of 'Use for Promo Rule Conditions' under Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes.

For example you could change SKU so that was usable.  Then in the Shopping Cart rule you can then set up a rule based on these attributes, and apply the discount if met e.g. when cart contains qty>1 of SKU x and qty>2 of SKU y give a discount of 10% on SKU x.